# Use of non-abstract method and constructor in an abstract class

Tags: c#, inheritance, abstract-class

I am beginner to Programming language. I have a query regarding abstract class.

Abstract class can't be instantiated then what is the use of nonabstract method and constructor in an abstract class .....?

please help....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It will make sense only when there are derived classes.

You may want some common methods to be implemented in the base class. Also, you may want to initialize a few thinhgs in the abstract class so you need a constructor.

Look at this example:

```
abstract class Fruit
{
    private Logger log;

    // init private stuff
    public Fruit() 
    {
        this.log = new Logger("C:\\Temp");
    }

    // do common functionality
    public int CalculatePrice(double weight)
    {
       return weight * GetPricePerKilo();
    }

    // specific stuff must be implemented by derived classes
    public abstract double GetPricePerKilo();
}

class Apple : Fruit
{
    // must implement in non-abstract derived class
    public override double GetPricePerKilo()
    {
        return 4.30;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks both of you......so the main difference is the "abstract" keyword allows me to define all or some of the properties of that abstract class in different derived class as per the derived class's requirement and also it provides some already defined properties ( method in this case ) which can be used while i am creating object of the derived class. am i right sir ??

Comment: @user2897975 If some methods or properties are abstract, the entire class must be abstract since it cannot be used if the implementation of e.g. a method is missing. And yes, basically you are right but 1) Don't confuse properties and methods and 2) It all comes into play at compile time, when a derived class is defined and not an object of that derived class.

Answer (score 1):

Abstract classes are there to abstract certain behaviour, while also forcing that you add at least some sort of behaviour to make it an actual object. Think of it as road vehicles. You could have an abstract class `RoadVehicle` that contains a non-abstract function `Drive`. If you then inherit from the abstract function, let's say a concrete class `Car`, we will already have access to the `Drive` behaviour.

If you don't want to predefine behaviour, you are better off using interfaces which only contain definitions of methods (and properties) every class implementing that interface should have. I.e. we could have an `IVehicle` interface that has a method `Move()`. Well, land vehicles, air vehicles and water vehicles all move in a different way and thus it makes no sense to predefine behaviour, while in our previous case the behaviour was the same and we could already add that behaviour to the abstract class.

Answer (score 0):

Abstract classes are most useful in situations where some member will have behavior which every implementation will handle independently.  Consider, for example, a `ReadableDoubleMatrix` class, with three properties:

```
int Rows {get;};
int Columns {get;}
double this[int row, int column] {get;}
```

The simplest general-purpose implementation might be an ImmutableArrayBackedMatrix class which contains a `double[,]` which is filled in when the class is constructed, but other implementations would include `IdentityMatrix` which contains a `size` value [`Rows` and `Columns` both return `size`, while `this[row, column]` will return `row==column ? 1.0 : 0.0`].  Because those derived classes have no fields in common, it would be senseless for the base class to include either.  Without any fields, however, there's nothing meaningful a base-class instance could do with those properties.

Note that even if though one could e.g. have the base class implement `Rows` and `Columns` to return 1, and `this` to return 0.0, and code might in some cases find such an object useful, there wouldn't be any reason code should want to have multiple instances of such an item.  Even if code had frequent need for such a matrix, and wanted it to be a different type from all the other matrices, it would generally be better to use for that purpose a sealed type.